# IEEE papers: reference of software used to design

Tags: publications, citations

In IEEE style, should I provide a citation to the 'product page' of general, commercial software used in design and simulations?

I've seen some papers do this:

"This antenna was designed with super-antenna-designer-5000 [3]" and then in the references you would see: 
"[3] Super antenna designer 5000 product page. Online at superantennadesigner5000.com/about"

I've also seen papers just not give a reference to the software when they mention it. After looking around online for a while I couldn't find any clear guidelines on what I should do here. On the one hand, I always like to go with the mindset that it tends to be better to refer to something too often than to omit it, after all, the reader can ignore things they don't care about, but cannot add things they don't know. At the same time, I feel like I can spend those 3 lines of text in my maximum-3-page paper on something more important. After all, there is not much useful info to be gained with linking to an about-page, nor is this an example of using previous research work to build on top of.

Comment: Frankly, most people don't care about a strict implementation of the IEEE style. A space-saving solution is to give the URL as part of the text: "The antenna was designed with super-antenna-designer-5000 (superantennadesigner5000.com)".

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I know people tend to have a lose interpretation of the style and don't care, but I do. It feels a bit hypocritical to insist on proper style and referencing to my students, just to then not do it right myself in actual scientific publications.

Comment: You already point to the trade-off between a sane use of space and 100% style compliance. If you strive for the latter, your best bet would be the IEEE style guidelines.